# How do I get snakemake to give me a full traceback?

Tags: snakemake, traceback

I'm attempting to debug a [bug I reported on snakemake](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2373).  The exception being raised is a `WorkflowError`.  It would really be helpful if I could see a full traceback for the exception, but the error printed in the snakemake log does not include the trace and I can't find an option that would tell snakemake to give me the trace.  I have tried `--debug`, `--debug-dag`, and `--verbose`.

I linked the bug report, but really, that's just an example.  Whether or not there is a bug is unrelated to my question.  I feel pretty confident there is a bug, but even if I'm wrong, knowing how to get snakemake to provide traces would be handy.

Comment: @Wayne - That comment seems to apply to user python code that's called from their workflow. Are you suggesting that I add `__import__('pdb').set_trace()` to the snakemake package code somewhere?

Comment: Sorry. It may help though in your case if you get an indication of where to put it in, but I can see not pertinent. Sorry; I'll delete.